# Cannot see VOIP calls in Wireshark 2.0.0

Tags: wireshark, voip, sip

I received a pcap dump from a site, running Cisco JTAPI, who's VOIP traffic I need to analyse. I use Wireshark's VOIP calls analyser via the menu:

[image]

The conversations display fine in Wireshark v1.10.8, but when I upgraded to Wireshark v2.0.0, no conversations are shown for the same pcap file.

Is there a bug in WS 2.0.0? Or am I the bug? (as usual xD)

PS: I unfortunately cannot share the pcap file as it is sensitive client data.

Answer (score 0):

If the capture have not started before the VoIP session then wireshark will not detect it. 
Workaround: select the "Try to decode RTP outside of conversations" (from Preferences -> Protocols -> RTP)

Comment: Not relevant as the calls are showing correctly in the older version of Wireshark.